# My remote key fob only works a foot from my door.

Tags: chevrolet, impala, fob

I have a 2006 Chevy Impala. I haven't had a remote key fob for about a year as I didn't need it over the summer and was out of the country in the fall. I replace the battery in the fob and re-sync it to the car. I have two different fobs and neither will lock, unlock or pop the trunk unless I am about a foot from the driver's door. Also, the remote start won't work at all. If I am in the car, the remote start clicks a little, but then nothing happens. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2):

The internal module that receives the signal probably had it's amplifier die. In order to make the signal from these small remotes work reliably, the low power signal from the key fob is received, amplified, and cleaned up to be a usable signal. If the circuit that performs the amplification fails then only very strong and close signals will work. Those Chevy Impalas typically have some good range too. I would suggest going to a junkyard and getting another receiver module. There is a remote learning sequence you can find easily online after you swap it out. Also the receiver is typically in the dash or under the center console.